# WCF - To Use [DataContract] or not with .NET 3.5 SP1?

Tags: wcf

I am working with WCF .NET 3.5 SP1 and have read that one does NOT have to decorate their Entities/Collections with such things as [DataMember], [DataConract], and/or [Serializable]?  What is the best way to go?  What have you all encountered?

I am on 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Using Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx).

> New complex types that you create must
>   have a data contract defined for them
>   to be serializable. By default, the
>   `DataContractSerializer` infers the data
>   contract and serializes all publicly
>   visible types. All public read/write
>   properties and fields of the type are
>   serialized. You can opt out members
>   from serialization by using the
>   `IgnoreDataMemberAttribute`. You can
>   also explicitly create a data contract
>   by using `DataContractAttribute` and
>   `DataMemberAttribute` attributes. This
>   is normally done by applying the
>   `DataContractAttribute` attribute to the
>   type. This attribute can be applied to
>   classes, structures, and enumerations.
>   The `DataMemberAttribute` attribute must
>   then be applied to each member of the
>   data contract type to indicate that it
>   is a data member, that is, it should
>   be serialized. For more information,
>   see [Serializable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656732.aspx).

Like @Terry said, it's probably better to proactively declare which properties you want to expose. This way you could future proof your code from unintentionally exposing fields when the base class adds a public property in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - so what are negatives w/ just implementing [Serializable] on top of each class?  That seems to do it, no?  I read in a recent book that [DataMember] and [DataContract] decoration is not needed anymore - its redundant w/ SP1.

Comment: See http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/ for the difference between XmlSerializer and DataContractSerializer. You can still get it to work without those attributes ("By default, the DataContractSerializer infers the data contract and serializes all publicly visible types."), but it's better to be explicit is what we are saying.

Answer (score 1):

I'm of the opinion that it won't hurt to proactively express you intent to use the class as a DataContract.  I would guess that a class that isn't serializable still won't be useful as a DataContract in SP1... :)

Comment: +1 - yes, be as explicit as possible - it won't hurt, and it's much clearer what your intent is.